# how to save celsius / fahrenheit Value

Tags: math, floating-point, precision

i am working on a app where the user can store a temperature.
he can choose between celsius / fahrenheit

now my question is, whats the best way to save the value?
IN a complete own format or as fahrenheit, rather celsius?

Just because
91.45F  &  91.46F  are both 33.03C  so would not make sense
to save in Celsius..

I am not a math prof. and don't know what other probs could appear.
So i just like to ask if someone has experience how to go around
any possible problem. I just like to save the value in a format so
i can be sure it will be always right recalculated what ever format
the user wish and entered before.

edit:
the User Input is just 2 values after Comma! 
edit2:
till now it looks the best way seems to always convert the user input into fahrenheit and save that with a precision like 5 values after comma. any other idea. otherwise i would soon close that topic :)

Comment: "91.45F & 91.46F are both 33.03C"? Really?

Comment: 91.45°F = 33.0277778°C. 91.46°F = 33.0333333°C. You don't have to be a math professor to understand rounding.

Comment: sorry.... it was just because the user input is just 2 commas :) i forgot to mention.

Comment: Just because you have one precision on user input that doesn't mean you can't store the values using a higher precision.

Comment: @stefan, you are right. thats what i meant. i could always convert to fahrenheit and save with a higher precision. does that sound to all of you the best way :) ?

Comment: yeah, except that fahrenheit is a weird unit. I'd store in celsius. a matter of taste, but I prefer standard units.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on what Matt Ball said, you need to remember that if you are doing any calculations on the stored number (besides simply retrieving it), it is best to store it as an integer value, rather than a floating point number.  So, if you need precision to the hundreds place, store the captured value as something like `temp = captured_value * 100`

Comment: yeah i guess till now i prefer: User enters F or C with 2 values after comma. I convert into F and save the capture Valued with lets say 5 Numbers after comma. Without writing a test app, would that keep me save? :)

Comment: Well, the important thing to remember is the difference between a `float` and an `int`.  As long as you store the input as an `int`, you will be safe.

Answer (score 1):

Store the value and units separately.

Comment: What will that achieve, as opposed to just picking a storage unit and performing the conversion before presentation? Or are you talking about storing the preferred **presentation** unit?

Comment: thats an idea i also thought about. but in another case i have database that i would like to select like (highest and lowest value)... with units separately I would had to convert. Thats the reason I would like to save in ONE Format that I can sort and reconvert in the format the User does need.

Answer (score 1):

$f = 91.45400000;

$c = ($f - 32) × (5/9);

$f = ($c × (9/5)) + 32;

You could store the values with more decimals and just display them with fewer..
That way you keep the presision.

echo "Farenheit: " . round($f, 2);

Comment: Depends what the data will be used for.
Could also consider how large the database would become.

If you are calculating year averages, or controlling temperatures in chemical prosesses etc.. add some decimals

Comment: 2 - if converting on each display.
I would use one field for storing either celcius or farenheit value (with 2 decimals in this case) and use another field to store wich it is (0/1).
Would also need an extra table to store users display choice then.

Then display the number with or without conversion to c or f.
Could use the tip to multiply by 100 before saving and then reverse to display.

Comment: what I mean is, the OP says he wants two decimal places, so I was trying to get you to suggest how many he needs to store to get this consistent after the unit conversion has been done.

Comment: I would use 3 decimals if I was storing this - if more where needed I guess they would also ask for more decimals in the user input.
- But I just would avoid storing it - and rather perform some math than perform more sql queries. (default to the most common type for your users).